# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll'

Tags: sql-server, 64-bit, wampserver

I have installed SQLSRV40.EXE and edited these lines

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; SQL SERVER DRIVER ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;x64

extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll

;x86

extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
```

in php.ini file.

but when I run Wampserver, there occur such errors

```
[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - ?? ?????? ????????? ??????.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - ?? ?????? ????????? ??????.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll' - %1 ?? ???????? ??????????? Win32.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll' - %1 ?? ???????? ??????????? Win32.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll' - %1 ?? ???????? ??????????? Win32.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll' - %1 ?? ???????? ??????????? Win32.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - ?? ?????? ????????? ??????.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - ?? ?????? ????????? ??????.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll' - %1 ?? ???????? ??????????? Win32.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll' - %1 ?? ???????? ??????????? Win32.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll' - %1 ?? ???????? ??????????? Win32.

 in Unknown on line 0

[13-Dec-2016 06:11:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll' - %1 ?? ???????? ??????????? Win32.

 in Unknown on line 0
```

in php error log file, and when I run my project, it shows me this error:

```
could not find driver
```

I searched all day but couldn't find :(

Comment: Need more info ... where does your php.ini file give the extension directory as? Also, you have added all those drivers but you only need TWO of them: A PDO driver, and a sqlsrv driver for the correct architecture type. You also want the non-thread safe drivers ('nts'), not the 'ts' ones.

Comment: I met the same problem when i use php 7.1.2. I change to php 7.0.16, it's resolved.